# How to subtract time from one column from time from another column

Tags: sql, oracle, time

I have an oracle database table with some configurations and some times. I need to subtract times from one column from times from another column. Here's an example

| config | configname | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name | 01-oct-23 12:30:00 | 03-oct-23 12:30:00 |
| 2 | name | 03-oct-23 12:29:00 | 05-oct-23 12:30:00 |
| 3 | name | 05-oct-23 12:29:30 | 07-oct-23 12:30:00 |
| 4 | name | 07-oct-23 12:29:50 |  |

The end time of one row is always going to be after the start time of the next row. What I'm trying to calculate is the gap (for example the gap between row 1 end and row 2 start is 60 seconds, the gap between row 2 end and row 3 start is 30 seconds). The config is a primary key and configname will be the same across configs. The final row will not have an end time.

I tried writing something using a max(end) where the configname is 'name' but it got a little wonky (I think because there is no value in the final config?)

What I am expecting is a result set that provides those gaps between one row's end and the next row's start, preferably including the config name of the row whose start we're calculating, since that will essentially say 'row 2 took 30 60 seconds to start'

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `LEAD` analytic function to get a value from the next row and subtract one date from another to get a difference as a number of days:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       ROUND(("end" - LEAD("start") OVER (ORDER BY config)) * 86400)
         AS seconds_difference
FROM   table_name t;
```

which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (config, configname, "start", "end") AS
SELECT 1, 'name', DATE '2023-10-01' + INTERVAL '0 12:30:00' DAY TO SECOND, DATE '2023-10-03' + INTERVAL '0 12:30:00' DAY TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'name', DATE '2023-10-03' + INTERVAL '0 12:29:00' DAY TO SECOND, DATE '2023-10-05' + INTERVAL '0 12:30:00' DAY TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'name', DATE '2023-10-05' + INTERVAL '0 12:29:30' DAY TO SECOND, DATE '2023-10-07' + INTERVAL '0 12:30:00' DAY TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'name', DATE '2023-10-07' + INTERVAL '0 12:29:50' DAY TO SECOND, NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| CONFIG | CONFIGNAME | start | end | SECONDS_DIFFERENCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name | 2023-10-01 12:30:00 | 2023-10-03 12:30:00 | 60 |
| 2 | name | 2023-10-03 12:29:00 | 2023-10-05 12:30:00 | 30 |
| 3 | name | 2023-10-05 12:29:30 | 2023-10-07 12:30:00 | 10 |
| 4 | name | 2023-10-07 12:29:50 | *null* | *null* |

or, as an interval:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       ("end" - LEAD("start") OVER (ORDER BY config)) DAY TO SECOND AS difference
FROM   table_name t
```

Which outputs:

| CONFIG | CONFIGNAME | start | end | DIFFERENCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name | 2023-10-01 12:30:00 | 2023-10-03 12:30:00 | +00 00:01:00.000000 |
| 2 | name | 2023-10-03 12:29:00 | 2023-10-05 12:30:00 | +00 00:00:30.000000 |
| 3 | name | 2023-10-05 12:29:30 | 2023-10-07 12:30:00 | +00 00:00:10.000000 |
| 4 | name | 2023-10-07 12:29:50 | *null* | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/smm-UyB7)

Comment: OK, so this is perfect for my question, but I've got a follow-up. I can't use this to determine all situations where the difference exceeds a certain value (and I can't do an order by the seconds_difference for obvious reasons). If I wanted to return all configs where the difference exceeded 30 seconds (and these would have different confignames), how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @BobJones Wrap the query in an outer query and filter in the outer query [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1XYmir-G). (As an aside, you can use `ORDER BY seconds_difference`)

Comment: Sorry, you're obviously correct, I meant that I couldn't use a where clause with seconds_difference (without wrapping it in an outer query). Poked around in [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/k1LUPxs8) so you can see my dilemma. i get these large seconds_difference values and i'm not sure why. when i filter specifically for name1 i don't get that large value. I'm sorry for taking so much of your time on this

Comment: @BobJones Your original sample data does not have different `configname`s so it was not clear that you wanted to restart the order for each one. Since it appears that you do then use `LEAD("start") OVER (PARTITION BY configname ORDER BY config)` [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8R0zpaHm)

Comment: @BobJones, why would wrapping it with an outer query be a problem? It's pretty my *the* way to filter on window or analytic functions...